# What is the equivalent of TestPropertyAttribute available for class, not method

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

Is there the equivalent of the [TestPropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testpropertyattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) available for a class? I'd like to mark a bunch of tests with a property, without having to mark each test.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is none. We don't have a TestProperty equivalent at the class level.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this use of the TestProperty class used in the initialize to set a class member. It sets a default and you mark the tests with different settings with the `[TestProperty("thing", "non-default")]`

```cs
[ClassInitialize()]
public void InitializeClass(TestContext testContext)
{
    // Changed by the [TestProperty("thing", "non-default")]
    if (TestContext.Properties.Contains("thing"))
        _thing = TestContext.Properties["thing"] as string;
    else
        _thing = "default";
}
```

Further explanation is [here](http://craigandera.blogspot.nl/2010/02/on-utility-of-testpropertyattribute_24.html).